# How do I read MNIST datasets without downloading, i.e from an already downloaded location in my computer?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to python and tensorflow. I was going through the tutorial for linear regression using MNIST. That's when i came across this problem.
I use the below code for downloading and extracting data.

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot = True)
```

So when I run this program once the data is downloaded into the location specified. And multiple run causes the data to be downloaded again. What should I do to simply extract already downloaded data.

Comment: Are you running it in the same directory every time? That's a relative path, so if you switch directories it's going to have to download again. Looking at [source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py#L234) it uses `maybe_download` which is in `base` and only downloads the file if it doesn't exist already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply provide the exact location as the first parameter for read_data_sets

```
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("C:/ABC/Desktop/MNIST_data/", one_hot = True)
```

If you encounter the same problem while extracting mnist data you can use this code bit

```
root = os.path.splitext(os.path.splitext(filename)[0])[0]
print(root)
if os.path.isdir(root) and not force:
    print('%s already present - %s.'%(root, filename))
else:
    print('Extracting data for %s.'%root)
    tar = tarfile.open(filename)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    tar.extractall(data_root)
    tar.close()

data_folders = [ 
                os.path.join(root, d) for d in sorted(os.listdir(root))
                if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root, d))
                ]
```

Here, **filename** specifies the location of the already extracted tar file and **data_root** is the destination to store data. You could define this code bit as afunction returning the data folders.

Comment: Thanks @Gautam .That was really helpful.